# Postman Global pre-request script that all collections inherit

Tags: postman

Postman is probably the most amazing piece of software I've ever encountered in my software development career.

However, there is something I'm stuck on and I believe there is an answer out there...

I have a huge pre-request script that I copy to each new postman collection that I create. The pre-request script does different things including setting the server to run my request on, generating reference numbers, and many other tasks.

The problem is that I have the to copy this code all over the place. Each Collection I create gets the same blob of code. And then as time moves forward I update my blob of code and then forget which collection has the latest updates.

I was told that it's possible to set up a global pre-request script in Postman that all collection will execute. I've spent some time searching the internet and I can't find the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: No, the root of script hierarchy is pre-request of collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do it over more "real collections" without any custom shell script.

If it would be possible, I think they would mention it here.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/

Postman supports from itself only one Pre-request Script for each "real collection" - but you could mimic "sub collections" of one upper collection by doing folders under the "real collection".

So the real collection would be ***my-server-collection*** - this one contains your pre-request script and every Rest API Controller is a subfolder under this collection - so you would get the same effect.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that it's possible to set up a global pre-request script in Postman that all collection will execute. I've spent some time searching the internet and I can't find the answer.

Did this come from Postman itself? I'm pretty sure Collection webhooks are set per collection, as this is a topic I've explored in depth before. I went to check just in case you could skip naming a collection to force it to `*` or something, but nope:

[image]

With that out of the day, the only suggestion I have to you is to create an utility collection that [traverses all collections](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/request/12959542-fa95fa93-5aa8-4146-94a6-bfebc1a578b4) with a given convention name, for example `PRS-X, PRS-Y`. For those collections your utility would [edit each collection](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/request/12959542-bc8b292b-ffbb-4c67-a2a1-2fc416e2aef8) to add/update the pre-request script.

As you probably know you could run that on-demand, schedule it, or initiate the run other automation (like an update to your pre-request script).

Answer (score 0):

You go to the **Environments** tab and click on **Create new Environment** icon.

In the **[Environment](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/managing-environments/#creating-environments)** windows add a name to it and a variable for your pre-request script. e.g. `preRequestScript` and set the value to your pre-request code. (Save it of course)

Lastly, you can go to your **Collections**, edit the one you want, and select the "Global" environment you created from the dropdown.

Once you finish, the global pre-request script will run before each request in your selected collection.